# Can a bookmarklet work across several pages

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm writing a bookmarklet to login to my bank and the navigate to my statement page and click a download button./

I know I can do the login part OK, but can the bookmarklet then run a navigate to a second page and click buttons etc on the second page

Comment: Not unless you click the bookmarklet icon a second time. Why not try making an extension for your chosen browser?

Comment: Short answer: no. Longer answer: look for an automation plugin for your browser instead. Additional: a button which automatically logs into your bank sounds like a bad idea, and something your bank will be very unhappy with you setting up. (Then again, they should really be deploying countermeasures against such automation themselves...)

Comment: @IMSoP, I did try those plugins but they were very flaky or involved learning a new language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bookmarklet that works on 2 pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481824/bookmarklet-that-works-on-2-pages)